# Postgres Error : Invalid Page header in block xxx, But Fine while run with 'Order By'

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

I run this query on Postgres 8.2 Database (Windows) :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table1 tb1 WHERE date='2019-03-06' ) tb1
    JOIN table2 tb2 ON
        tb2.tb1_id = tb1.id
WHERE
    tb2.date ='2019-03-06'
```

then i got this error message :

> ERROR: invalid page header in block 11729 of relation
>   "table1_pkey" SQL state: XX001

But, when I add `Order By` clause, this query is running well.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table1 tb1 WHERE date='2019-03-06' ORDER BY id) tb1  
    JOIN table2 tb2 ON
        tb2.tb1_id = tb1.id
WHERE
    tb2.date = '2019-03-06'
```

AFAIK, error "invalid page header in block xxx" mostly because of bad memory or a bad drive (link : [Postgres Database Error Invalid Page Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899040/postgres-database-error-invalid-page-header)).

But, how could it run when I add `Order By`clause ?

Comment: Could you run `EXPLAIN` for those queries? That might explain it (no pun intended). Probably using a different index or something. All indexes, data etc are in separate files so if one is corrupted the others may very well be ok

Comment: Postgres 8.2 is long dead and forgotten. You should really plan an upgrade to a [supported version](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) **now**

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, this is the return while i run EXPLAIN

"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..27811.22 rows=1 width=2029)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..24881.40 rows=307 width=8)"
"        Filter: (table2. date = '2019-03-06'::date)"
"  ->  Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1  (cost=0.00..9.53 rows=1 width=2021)"
"        Index Cond: (table2.tb1_id = table1.id)"
"        Filter: (table1.date = '2019-03-06'::date)"

Comment: I assume that’s for the first one, how about the second?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query has trouble evaluating what columns are actually returned by `SELECT * FROM table1`, so it does not know if `tb1.id` exists and is a primary key.

As I see your query, you could do a simple join like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 tb1  
JOIN 
    table2 tb2 ON tb2.tb1_id = tb1.id
WHERE
    tb2.date = '2019-03-06' AND tb1.date = '2019-03-06'
```

The results should be the same. Yes, this could bring a penalty in performance, but it should not be significant.

Comment: i've try it, but the result is still :

ERROR: invalid page header in block 11729 of relation "table1_pkey" SQL state: XX001